# Copying file to destination directory overwrites directory with file

Tags: solaris, file-copy

A script which runs on Solaris uses `cp` to copy a single file into a destination directory.

On occasion this `cp` command will overwrite that destination directory with the file being copied

For example when trying to move `test.txt` to the directory `/home/user/Dest`:

`cp /home/user/Docs/test.txt /home/user/Dest`

the entire `Dest` directory becomes a text file with the contents of `test.txt` which has been renamed `Dest`.

I am able to get around this issue by using:
`cp /home/user/Docs/test.txt /home/user/Dest/test.txt`

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you should issue:

```
cp /home/user/Docs/test.txt /home/user/Dest/
```

instead of

```
cp /home/user/Docs/test.txt /home/user/Dest
```

The `/` at the end means the destination is a directory not a file.

Answer (score 3):

*What could be causing this issue?*

Given

```
cp /home/user/Docs/test.txt /home/user/Dest
```

if the directory `/home/user/Dest` does not already exist, the file `/home/user/Docs/test.txt` will be copied to a *file* named `/home/user/Dest`.

As @HamdiKadri answered, appending a `/` to the destination as `/home/user/Dest/` ensures that `/home/user/Dest` is treated as a directory.  You can also write that as

```
cp /home/user/Docs/test.txt /home/user/Dest/.
```

Comment: This could possibly happen (but I wouldn't know under what circumstances) if the home directories are automatically mounted upon access. Such directories do literally not exist until files within them are accessed, at which point the auto mounter mounts them.

Answer (score 0):

*What could be causing this issue?*

`cp /home/user/Docs/test.txt /home/user/Dest`

By giving the above command, you are copying the content of `test.txt` file into `/home/user/Dest` file. If the file will not be there already, it will create a new file named `Dest` and copy the content into that. To make sure that your file is copied in the desired directory give `/` in the end. e.g.

`cp /home/user/Docs/test.txt /home/user/Dest/`

Also, if you are using the terminal then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to avoiding these mistakes.